# Eclipse doesn't save the previous settings like workspace & Plug-ins

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse Neon on my MacBook & every time I start Eclipse it prompts me for my workspace again and again even though I set it as my default one.

Same goes for the plug-ins I have installed , I need to install eclipse decompiler every time I load eclipse.

I get an error like : "This wizard helps you to import and reinstall previously installed plug-ins. It is triggered because
either you are launching eclipse for the first time or your Eclipse has been updated."

Can someone please assist me with this issue ?

Comment: try running it as root (if that is possible, I am a Windows [:-| user), could be a file/directory protection issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem after updating my Mac to Sierra: Eclipse would not remember the default workspace. After moving Eclipse into the Application folder, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

The issue seems to come from a Mac OSX Sierra feature called 'path randomization' (see eclipse bug 507328).  The actual solution to avoid the path randomization seems to be for eclipse to provide signed .dmg images (bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=461670).

Two workarounds that I can suggest are:

- Start from the eclipse oomph installer when installing eclipse (see https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=rview&goto=1754574#msg_1754574)
- Start the actual eclipse executable file instead of opening the .App container